# How to run the jenkins cookbook downloaded from chef supermaket?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm new to using Chef to bootstrap a Node. I have an ubuntu server. In that i wanted to install Jenkins using jenkins cookbook available in supermarket. For that i added the following commands.

```
$ knife cookbook site download jenkins
```

and

```
$ knife cookbook site install jenkins
```

I want to know how to run those recipes now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
I recommend starting to learn chef with the [official tutorials](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stephen, but i wanted to know the command which could help me precisely in what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're keeping a lot of secrets. Are you using Chef server or Chef solo? Frankly speaking: "Add the cookbook to the run list" is what you want. Depends on the server/solo model, how to do that.
For the long term (to adjust the setup), create a wrapper cookbook around the _jenkins_ cookbook. Understood?

Comment: If you want a command (for the case that you are using chef server, without berkshelf and without a wrapper cookbook):
`knife cookbook upload jenkins && knife boostrap ... -r "recipe[jenkins]"`

Comment: I'm not using chef server to upload the cookbook. I'm directly downloading the cookbook from the supermarket and now i want to run that cookbook locally.

Answer (score 1):

To run a cookbook locally you need to use chef-solo or chef-zero. Invoke chef-zero with the `-z` argument and pass in a run list with the `-o` argument.

```
chef-client -z -o "recipe[jenkins::master]"
```

You would typically want to wrap a community cookbook in a [wrapper cookbook](https://blog.chef.io/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right) so that you can customize various options.

Comment: Why use `-o` versus Mark's answer with `-r`?

Comment: `-r` permanently sets the run list, while `-o` only sets it for that single run.

Comment: @chicks When running in local mode (-z) "-r" and "-o" are effectively the same. If I was running chef client manually, while connected to a chef server, I'd use "-o".

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would run a chef server containing the cookbooks and "bootstrap" nodes against this server.

It is possible to run chef locally, but you'll need to install the [chefdk](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/), which includes [berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) for cookbook dependency management.

**Step 1:** Create Berkshelf file

Berkshelf file to specify the cookbooks to be downloaded:

```
$ cat Berksfile
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

cookbook "jenkins"
```

**Step 2:** Run chef-client in local mode

```
# Download cookbooks to local "cookbooks" directory
berks vendor cookbooks

# Run chef client in "local mode" 
sudo chef-client -z -r "jenkins::master"
```